# What kind of subset is Spec(R_P) in Spec(R)?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

While trying to prove some properties of a subset of a prime spectrum I arrived at the following question: Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $P \in \mathrm{Spec}(R)$. We can consider $\mathrm{Spec}(R_P)$ as a subset of $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$. My question is: What kind of subset (subspace) is this? I guess it is not true that $\mathrm{Spec}(R_P)$ is open, right? Is it true that a neighborhood of the generic point in $\mathrm{Spec}(R_P)$ is a neighborhood of $P$ in $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$?

Comment: Isn't Spec$(R_P)$ (considered as a subset of Spec$(R)$) the complement of $V(P)$? That would make it open. (This question seems a bit elementary for MO.)

Comment: Well, V(P) contains all $Q \supset P$, so its complement is the set of all $Q \not\supset P$. But $Spec(R_P)$ consists of all $Q$ with $Q \cap (R \setminus P) = \emptyset$, so $Q \subset P$. This is not the complement of $V(P)$. Am I wrong? This would be great. :-) 

Comment: @Georg: You are of course right, since spectra are not necessarily totally ordered by inclusion.

Comment: $\mathrm{Spec}(R_f)$ is the complement of $V(f)$ (for $f \in R$), but $\mathrm{Spec}(R_P)$ is not the complement of $V(P)$ (for $P \in \mathrm{Spec}(R)$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already said, in general the image is not open and even not constructible. But it is pro-constructible (that is, locally an intersection of locally constructible subsets, see EGA IV.1.9.4, and 1.9.5(ix) because $X:=\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is affine hence quasi-compact).

Denote this image by $S$. This is a subset of $X$ having exactly one closed point and which is stable by generization as pointed out by Martin. I claim that these two properties characterize all possibles images $S$ when $X$ is noetherian (this hypothesis could be weakened if we notice that $S$ is always quasi-compact, but I don't know how exactly). Here $X$ needs not be affine.

Indeed, let $s$ be the unique closed point of $S$. Let us show $S$ is the intersection of all open neighborhoods of $s$ in $X$ (then it is easy to show $S$ is the image of $\mathrm{Spec}(O_{X,s})$). Let $U$ be any open neighborhood of $s$ in $X$. Then $S\cap (X\setminus U)$ is noetherian hence admits a closed point if non-empty. But this would be a closed point of $S$ different from $s$. So $S\cap (X\setminus U)=\emptyset$ and $S\subseteq U$.  Conversely, any point $x\in X$ in the intersecion of all $U\ni s$ is a generization of $s$ (otherwise the complementary of $\overline{\{ x\}}$ is an open neighborhood of $s$ not containing $x$).

Answer (score 4):

Take $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $P=0$. Then, ${\rm Spec}(R_P)$, considered canonically as a subset of ${\rm Spec}(R)$, consists precisely of the point $0$. In particular, it is not open in ${\rm Spec}(R)$. Hence, it is not a neighbourhood in ${\rm Spec}(R)$ of $0$, despite $0$ being the generic point of ${\rm Spec}(R_P)$ and ${\rm Spec}(R_P)$ being an open neighbourhood of its generic point in itself.

You might want to have a look at Section I.2.5, especially Proposition I.2.5.2, of EGA [1970 edition] (or Section I.2.4 in the first edition) to get some more general information about your situation.

Comment: This is about the fact that $Spec(R_P)$ is homeomorphic to the "generization" of $P$ in $Spec(R)$? Does this perhaps imply an answer about my neighborhood question?

Answer (score 3):

If $X$ is a scheme and $x \in X$, then the canonical morphism $j_x : \mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x}) \to X$ is a homeomorphism onto its image. The image consists of those $y \in X$ which generalize $x$, i.e. satisfy $x \in \overline{\{y\}}$. Locally, this is just the classification of prime ideals in the localization.

It follows that that the image is closed under generalizations, and contains $x$. In general, I doubt that anything more can be said.

Every open subset is stable under generalizations. The converse is true for constructible subsets of noetherian sober topological spaces (see [here](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0542)). Chevalley's theorem implies that the image of a morphism of finite presentation is constructible. However, $j_x$ is almost never of finite presentation.

For example, when $x$ is a generic point of $X$, this means that the image of $j_x$ equals $\{x\}$, which is usually neither open nor closed.

Answer (score 2):

$\text{Spec } R_P$ is by the usual correspondences the set of all primes of $R$ which are contained in $P$.  In particular, it is somehow dual to $V(P) = $ the set of primes which are contained in $P$.  It is not generally equal to the complement of $V(P)$ plus the point $P$ itself (this is very rare although does occur in all valuation rings as Fred pointed out in the comments).  It is not open, $\text{Spec } R_P$ as a subset of $R$ is closed under generization.

For example:  I like to think of say $\text{Spec }$ of the local ring of the origin in $\mathbb{A}^2$ as the origin itself, some germ of every curve passing through the origin, and the generic point.

Comment: "...does occur in some valuation rings": This is in fact the case in every valuation ring.

Answer (score 2):

It is a limit of open subsets (the subsets containing $P$.) Thus, though it is not set-theoretically an open subset, it behaves scheme-theoretically like an open subset.

Comment: What do you mean by "behaves scheme-theoretically like an open subset."?

Comment: e.g. if a property holds on every sufficiently small neighborhood of a point, it usually holds on the local ring.